# Transmission is not working

Tags: transparency, glass

I tried to make a glass following youtube tutorial. In that video, if you raise the transmission value to close to 1, it becomes transparent, but I can't.

I know. It's really simple! But I don't know why!

[image]

It looks like glass but not see through.

Comment: try changing render engine to cycles.

Comment: Actually, it's still same result in cycle render view. not only in render preview but in render view. thank you for your comment:)